# Why is "-H" command not found?

Tags: centos, sudo

I have a strange error with linux somehow interpreting `sudo -H` as two separate commands.

I'm on Cent OS 7, and I get the following:

```
/var/tmp/<random string>: line 8: -H: command not found
```

This is very vexing to me.  Why would it not know this uption of `sudo`?

Comment: Type the exact command you used, and also the output of `sudo -V` and `type sudo`

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you have an alias or bash function that is suppressing your call to `sudo`. Try running the command with the full pathname for `sudo` (`/usr/bin/sudo`) on both systems, and type `type sudo` to see if there is an alias or bash function that is being called instead of the executable.

If there is, check the usual places like `~/.bashrc` for where it is being defined so you can remove it.

Alternatively, it could be unrelated to `sudo`, and instead be related to whatever script you are calling with `sudo`.